# Can I have form tag inside View in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can we put form tag inside view in MVC. I need to keep report controller inside the form tag which is inside the view. It works fine. I am new to MVC, can anybody tell is it the correct way to work with.

Comment: what do you mean by "I need to keep report controller inside the form tag" ?? Post some code coz it feels like you're doing it quite wrong..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put form tags in views. Forms are standard html tags, so it's not a problem. You can also put form tags with runat="server" if you want to render some server controls that require it.

Comment: Using server controls in an ASP.NET MVC application is not considered as a good practice.